# number format in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-report-designer

I am working on pentaho report designer 
HereI created one cross tab report. When I preview the report it is showing me results as below

name          total

A              598.00

B               273.00

c               124.00

d                0.23

e                0.23

f                0.00

g                273.00

In the above results I want only the particular values should look in decimal format 
Like I want only o.23 in the above result look like in decimal format and all the other I want to look like integer with out any decimal portions.
Is there any expression I can write.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Pentaho report designer, you must define a data type for your inputs(https://www.screencast.com/t/y440gotpnp). The case that you describe could be treated with a formula(check the floating numbers e.g. different to "00" ... ) and as an output data type you could use a string(text)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use **Truncate** function inside you query, something like **truncate(total,2)**, this will keep **2** digits after the '**,**' and if your totals end with **00** they won't be shown automatically.